# Hide specific button on android navigation bar

Tags: android, navigationbar

I have another question for you:

Is there a way to **hide a specific virtual button** from android navigation bar?

My particular case is hide **recent apps** button. I've searched in some posts about this, but they mention how to hide or disable navigation bar. I just need to **hide one virtual button from navigation bar**.

I hope that you can give me an answer, thanks!

**Update:**
Somebody told me that Airwatch app from VM-Ware does this customization

Comment: Why not hide the entire navigation bar https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation ? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It could not be an answer that I expected, because I want to hide just one button from navigation bar, also, I read your link but it mentions that if you press the navigation bar zone, android sets nav bar visible

Comment: Seems similar issue already has some solutions, might helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979005/block-disable-recent-apps-button

Comment: that issue is for block/disable the button, my question is just for how to hide it, thanks for responding

Answer (score 2):

It is currently impossible to make an App-specific customization, but it is possible to make a device-specific modification on Navigation Bar, starting from Android 8.0 (Oreo) by unlocking **System UI Tuner**.

[image]

[image]

However, **do consider the limitation** as both Navigation Bar and System UI Tuner ability is pre-defined by OEMs. Which means **we cannot customize more than the given customization choices**, and different device might introduce different customization capabilities.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but I don't want to add more options on navigation bar, I used that app and I gave it necessary permissions to see all features, but unfortunately this app does not help me.

Comment: @isthemartin If System UI Tuner doesn't help you, then I am afraid there is nothing you can do for it, as it came from the manufacturer that way. I am certain each manufacturer also follows standards (or ISO) for Android devices to always have at least 3 buttons at Navigation Bar. About VM-Ware capability, to be honest, it is always possible (and easier) to tweak/customize VM or Emulators, but NOT real devices. I hope this answers your curiosity, as I have provided the best possible answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the navigation bar from your application; you do not have access to these settings. Instead, what you can do is **using adb to hide the navigation bar** and use only the navigation inside your app. You can follow [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/361168/how-to-get-gesture-navigation-on-any-android-phone/) of XDA-dev and their application called "Navigation Gesture", you will find the adb command.